# Parameter passing to \verb|| environment

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

I happen to write the following code over and over again.

```
{\color{blue}\verb|>|} {\footnotesize\verb|HI|}
```

So, I came up with the following code to make it a command.

```
\newcommand{\result}[2]{%
{\color{#1}\verb|>|} {\footnotesize\verb|#2|} 
}
```

The problem is that the result is not what I expected, there are `|` characters attached.

What might be wrong? I need to have the `verbatim` environment kept as the result can contain some characters something like `$`, `\` ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\result}[2]{%
{\color{#1}$>$} {\footnotesize \verb|#2|} 
}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
{\color{blue}\verb|>|} {\footnotesize\verb|HI|} 

\result{red}{HI}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### ADDED

- For the original source, `\verb|>|` should have been `$>$`. I updated the source example.
- Following Willie's answer, I modified the command

  `\newcommand{\result}[2]{{\color{#1}$>$} {\footnotesize\texttt{#2}}}`

It seems fine, but with **`multicols`** environment, the `footnotesize` font, gives some blank spaces before its printing of characters. I attach the screen capture and source code.

[image]

It seems that line break causes this problem, by adding `\mbox` inside the `\texttt`, I could remove the blank.

```
\newcommand{\result}[2]{{\color{#1}$>$} {\footnotesize\texttt{\mbox{#2}}}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\result}[2]{{\color{#1}$>$} {\footnotesize\texttt{\mbox{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\resultp}[2]{{\color{#1}$>$} {\small\texttt{\mbox{#2}}}}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\noindent\result{green}{Welcome to my project! These are your args: (a b c)}\\ \result{green}{hello}\\ \result{green}{HI my\string_name}
\vskip 2ex
\noindent\resultp{green}{Welcome to my project! These are your args: (a b c)}\\ \resultp{green}{hello}\\ \resultp{green}{HI}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile for me: ! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \result{red}{HI}

Comment: do you still have a question here, or have you resolved it?

Comment: @Michael : Willie gave me enough hints to solve my issue, and I updated my post by answering. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am surprised that it even compiled for you (your test example). On my installation

```
This is pdfTeX, Version
3.1415926-1.40.10 (Web2C 2009) entering extended mode 
(./test.tex 
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24> 
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh yphenation, pinyin, bulgarian, russian, ukrainian, basque, french, loaded. 
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls 
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class 
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) 
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty 
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg) 
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def) 
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def)) (./test.aux)

! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  
H <return>  for immediate help.  ...    

                                                   l.12 \result{red}{HI}
```

The reason is that [`\verb` is a very fragile command](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin). The suggestion from the TeX faq I linked to is to replace `\verb` by `\texttt`, and when you type arguments to the `\result` as you defined above, use `\string` to escape the problematic characters. See also ['the string command'](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/string).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the trouble. I elaborated the question more, could you check that? 
And for the \string command, there doesn't seem to be a lot of example. Could you give some more hints?

Comment: Did you look at the Link that I posted? The `\string` command converts the one character that follows it into a string. So you can type `\string_` to get the underscore character, or `\string{` to get the open brace character etc. In your revised example you are almost surely using the command wrong.

Comment: I see, I missed the link, and I updated the example.

Comment: Ah, you missed the link. That's alright. I hope for your sake you didn't try to Google "LaTeX string". It is one of those seemingly harmless combinations of words...

Comment: I happen to google "LaTeX string", and I saw a bunch of nasty pictures.

Comment: @prosseek: never mention latex to google.  it gets all excited, and usually provides misleading answers.  (and anyway, \string is a tex primitive, not defined by the latex macros.)

Answer (score 4):

You could also define your own `\verb`-like command using `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand\myvrb{O{blue}v}{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\(>\)} \texttt{\footnotesize#2}}

\begin{document}

\myvrb|HI|

\myvrb[red]|HI|

\myvrb|&$#|

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a modicum of coercion, the [verbatim](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=verbatim) package can be made to *almost* do what you want.  The "almost" is because you have to use an environment instead of a command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{result}[1]{%
\def\verbatim@processline{\the\verbatim@line\ }%
\def\@verbatim{\the\every@verbatim
  \obeylines
  \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
  \verbatim@font
}%
\def\endverbatim{\endgroup}%
\noindent
{\color{#1}\texttt{>}}
\footnotesize
\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here are your results:

\begin{result}{red}
greetings
\end{result}

\begin{result}{green}
A load of *@&$!)%*#$
\end{result}

\end{document}
```

In short, I looked a the definitions in the `verbatim` package and stripped out everything that looked as though it might insert a newline, thus making the verbatim environment work on one line instead of several and meaning that it doesn't start or end with new lines.  Then I put this inside a new environment so that the old `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` construct still works as it should.

Caveat: Anything extra on the line `\end{result}` gets discarded (LaTeX warns about this).  So if you want to take out the `\noindent` from the `result` environment and have the input more like in the example in the question, the code will have to be:

```
\noindent\begin{result}{red}
greetings
\end{result}
\\
\begin{result}{green}
A load of *@&$!)%*#$
\end{result}
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible implementation with Martin Scharrer’s `newverbs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newverbcommand{\colorverb@verb}{}{\endgroup}
\newcommand{\colorverb}[2][]{%
  \leavevmode\begingroup
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\color{#2}}%
  {\color[#1]{#2}}%
  \colorverb@verb
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\colorverb{green}|abc{\}|

\colorverb{red!20}?abc|}?

\colorverb[HTML]{A021C2}|abc{\}|

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `expl3`; loading `xcolor` is optional if you need to use its user-level facilities such as `\definecolor` or `\colorlet`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { prosseek/flexiverb }
 {
  color .tl_set:N = \l__prosseek_flexiverb_color_tl,
  model .tl_set:N = \l__prosseek_flexiverb_model_tl,
  font .tl_set:N = \l__prosseek_flexiverb_font_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\flexiverb}{O{}v}
 {
  \mbox
   {
    \keys_set:nn { prosseek/flexiverb } { #1 }
    \tl_if_empty:VTF \l__prosseek_flexiverb_model_tl
     {
      \color_select:V \l__prosseek_flexiverb_color_tl
     }
     {
      \color_select:VV \l__prosseek_flexiverb_model_tl \l__prosseek_flexiverb_color_tl
     }
    \use:c { verbatim@font }
    \l__prosseek_flexiverb_font_tl
    #2
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_select:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_select:nn { VV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% how to define a command based on \flexiverb
\NewDocumentCommand{\redverb}{}{\flexiverb[color=red!80]}

\begin{document}

\flexiverb[color=red!80]|abc}|

\redverb|abc}|

\flexiverb[color=A021C2,model=HTML,font=\footnotesize]|abc{\}|

\end{document}
```

[image]